# Dropdown shows empty when selected Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, web, setstate

ReactJs

When I use `e.target.value` my dropdown gets updated but when I use `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text`, my dropdown doesn't get updated but the text is actually set to the state declared. What could be the problem? I need help, please.

On my onChange, I have:

```
handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value, selectedIndex, options} = e.target

        if (name == "fundingInstitutionName") {
            this.setState({
                fundingInstitutionName: options[selectedIndex].text,
                bank_code: value
            }, () => {
                this.validateAccountNum();
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                [name]: value
            }, () => {
                this.validateAccountNum();
            })
        }

    }
```

while I have this in the select dropdown,

```
<select 
     className="form-control kyc-input"
     value={this.props.state["fundingInstitutionName"]}
     onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e)}
     name="fundingInstitutionName" required>

     <option value="">Select bank</option>
        {bNames.map((bName, i) => {
            return <option key={i} value={bName.code}>
                        {bName.name}
                    </option>
         })}

</select>
```

NB: I need both the value and the text since they are separate.

Comment: Provide the code so I can see what actually happen.

Comment: Add console.log for the values that you set from e.target and see what you get.

Comment: I get the value which corresponds to the bName.code and the text which corresponds to bName.name which are both intended but the dropdown doesn't update physically, I mean it is empty( it doesn't show at all) @Rahamin

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the select's value from `this.props.state["fundingInstitutionName"]`.

I assume that you meant to set it from
`this.state["fundingInstitutionName"]`.

And one more thing: in `handleChange` you are supposed to set the state variable that you set the select's value from, but sometimes you do:

```
this.setState({
  [name]: value
}
```

Which will not be reflected in the select's value...